# Something wrong with my code?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledbcommand

Is there something wrong with my code? I'm having a " *Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid*" error.

Function called (GetNoofHoursOfTImeIn):

```
Public Shared Function GetNoofHoursofTImeIn(ByVal search As String, ByVal dfrom As   DateTime, ByVal dto As DateTime) As DataTable
Dim dtoffenseinfo As New DataTable

If Not DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then       
    DBConnection.Open()
End If

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = DBConnection
    cmd.CommandText = _
            "SELECT SUM(No_of_Hour) AS THour FROM EmployeeAttendance " & _
            "WHERE EmployeeID = ? " & _
                "AND WorkingDate BETWEEN ? AND ?"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", search)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dfrom.Date)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dto.Date)
    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(dtoffenseinfo)
    End Using
End Using

DBConnection.Close()
Return dtoffenseinfo
End Function
```

Code behind:

```
 txtPresentDays.Text = ClsAttendance.GetNoofHoursofTImeIn(EmployeeID.Text, MyDateString, MyDateString2).Rows(0).Item("THour")
```

I know this error is common but until now I don't get quite the idea how or why I'm getting this.

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Answer (score 1):

You get a null value when there are zero records that match the condition. You can use the `iif` function to turn that value into a zero:

```
SELECT IIF(SUM(No_of_Hour) Is Null, 0, SUM(No_of_Hour)) ...
```

Comment: @ProgrammingDreamer: Sorry, I was reading some article that had the wrong information about how `isnull` works in Access. You can use the `iif` function instead. I corrected the code above.

Comment: Alright I'm not getting an error anymore. But I'm not retrieving any data either. I have a strong feeling my dates' formatting between my database's data and DateTimePickers value don't match then. Many thanks Sir Guffa for the code I'm sure it will solve more of those errors in the future!

Comment: Minor point: there are almost no instances where 'IIf' is appropriate - use the 'If' operator instead.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Are you saying that `iif` is inappropriate? I don't find anything to support that.

Comment: @ProgrammingDreamer: When you are using parameters you shouldn't have to worry about formatting, as the database driver should take care of that. Start by checking that you get the correct `DateTime` values into the method.

Comment: @Guffa respectfully, yes sir. Actually retrieving DateFrom.Value as "#6/1/2014 10:38:49 PM#" and DateTo.Value as "#6/15/2014 10:38:49 PM#", but returning nothing. In MS Access, I have 6/9/2014, and 6/13/2014. :D

Comment: @Guffa: The "If" operator does what "IIf" is intended to do, without the negative aspects ("IIf" is a method call and all arguments are evaluated, unlike the "If" operator).

Comment: You should also be able to use Nz(SUM(No_of_Hour), 0). The Nz function checks the first parameter for a null value and returns the second if true.  Just another option.